# Animation not working on android 4.2.2 Jellybean

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

Here is the issue-
Animation not working on Android 4.2.2 Jelly Bean (Samsung Galaxy duos-gt s-7582)
but it is working on all other versions

Source 
1.XML 1

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:fromXDelta="100%p"
 android:toXDelta="0"
 android:duration="500"/>

 </set>
```

and 
 1. XML 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:fromXDelta="0"
 android:toXDelta="-100%p"
 android:duration="500"/>

 </set>
```

Class File source-

```
Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Day.class);
            startActivity(i);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation,R.anim.animation2);
            finish();
```

Comment: which one? how do you start it?

Comment: both are not working... @pskink

Comment: i mean working but not on 4.2.2 (JellyBean) @pskink

Comment: do you really. think that so simple animations could not work ?

Comment: but its happening...
working on my devices like galaxy tab, kindle..

Comment: i am also trying to google it and here is the link what i found!
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=54502 @pskink

Comment: so you have bad luck, since you dont want to show any code i dont think anybody could help you

Comment: ohk i have edited my source @pskink

Comment: and now check if you have animations enabled in your device: settings - display - animations

Comment: hmm it is good idea...
thnxx a lot.... @pskink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gotta......

Here is the Answer it is the device Specific issue.
Not 4.2.2 
Please Change the Settings in Device.